# creating a hotel database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

So far I have got a table (Hotels) and it contains:

```
1.HotelName(PK)
2.starRating
3.costperPerson
```

Now as you all know every hotel have many bedroom options such as:

- 2-bedroom(bedroom for 2)
- 3-bedroom
- 4-bedroom

And each bedroom option has booking availability, the part about the bedroom options and it availability is a bit confusing, any ideas on how to make it.

Do you think that I should create a column for each and every bedroom-option?

After creating this table I should be able to write SQL query that match for instance a family of 4 with the 4-bedroom option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create a column for every type of room option.

It would be easier to have three tables. Rooms, Options and a table that links them both together (RoomOptions). Using the roomID and optionID you can add as many rows as there are options to the RoomOptionsTable.

E.g

**Room Table**

RoomID, HotelID, Room Number, BaseCost

**Options**

OptionID, Name, AdditionalCost

**RoomOptions**

RoomID, OptionID

This way, you can have loads of options like smoking, non smoking, double bed etc. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would create rooms table and rooms_type table. Reason is simple, if the hotel decides to have larger rooms or remove one rooms, you can manage that on user interface ( when you build one ). Also, I would create reservations table, since your rooms are constant.

Also, be aware that this site is not homework solver :)